# NSFileManager Create a .app like file/folder in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I'd like to create a folder/file (similar to how the .app files/folders work) so that I can have a directory within my file. But still show the document icon that I setup via the xcode project interface under the info panel.

No idea how to go about this, any ideas?

> **Solution:**

So basically, you just hit an option in Xcode under the document saying that you do want it to be a bundle. Then you just create a folder with the extension you have in your document (info.plist). Thanks y'all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for are [Packages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_%28OS_X%29).

See [About Bundles](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH100-SW1) and [Document Packages](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/DocumentPackages/DocumentPackages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH106-SW1) for more details.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Do you know of any code examples of creating a bundle programatically